# Lookup field based CAML query returns the entire list instead of matching data

Tags: office-365, caml-query, mvc

I m using O365 List called Employee with lookup field. When I query the list based on the lookup column it will returns all list Item instead the matching data. Could you please help me. 
Using MVC asp.net.

**Home controller**

```
[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult FillCity(int depid = 2)
        {            
            CamlQuery querySelectedDepartment = new CamlQuery();
            querySelectedDepartment.ViewXml = "<Where><And><Eq><FieldRef Name='Department_x003a_ID' />< Value Type = 'Lookup' >" + depid + "</Value></Eq><FieldRef Name="ID"><Value Type="Integer">1</FieldRef></Eq></And></Where>";
            var Departments = SharePointService.GetSelectedDepManagers(spContext, querySelectedDepartment).ToDictionary(x => x.UserId, x => x.ManagerName);
            var j = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Departments);
            return Json(j, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

**Sharepointservices.sc file**

```
public static List<LocalLeaveAddinWeb.Models.Manager> GetSelectedDepManagers(LocalLeaveAddinWeb.SharePointContext spContext, CamlQuery camlQuery)
        {
            managers = new List<LocalLeaveAddinWeb.Models.Manager>();
            using (var clientContext = spContext.CreateUserClientContextForSPHost())
            {
                if (clientContext != null)
                {
                    List lstDepartmentManagers = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("EmployeeList");
                    ListItemCollection lstDepartmentManagerItems = lstDepartmentManagers.GetItems(camlQuery);
                    clientContext.Load(lstDepartmentManagerItems);
                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                    if (lstDepartmentManagerItems != null)
                    {
                        foreach (var lstDepartmentItem in lstDepartmentManagerItems)
                        {
                            managers.Add(
                            new LocalLeaveAddinWeb.Models.Manager
                            {
                                ManagerName = lstDepartmentItem["Title"].ToString(),
                                UserId=Convert.ToInt32(lstDepartmentItem["EmployeeID"]),

                            });
                    }
                }
            }
        }
            return managers;
        }
```

**SP List**
[image]

Comment: Can you please make your code in a proper format as it is looking messy right now?

Comment: You forget to add a closing tag for Value for type integer.

Comment: REST might be simpler to use here

Answer (score 0):

Please try this CAML query:  You have missed the `<Eq>` tag for second fieldref tag.

```
<View><Query>
    <Where>
        <And>
            <Eq><FieldRef Name='Department_x003a_ID' LookupId='TRUE' /><Value Type = 'Lookup'>" + depid + "</Value></Eq>
            <Eq><FieldRef Name="ID"><Value Type="Integer">1</FieldRef></Eq>
        </And>
    </Where>
</Query></View>
```

Hope this will help you!

Answer (score 0):

Please try changing CAML Query to:

```
querySelectedDepartment.ViewXml = "<View><Query><Where><And><Eq><FieldRef Name='Department' LookupId='TRUE' /><Value Type='Lookup'>" + depid + "</Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name="ID"><Value Type="Integer">1</Value></FieldRef></Eq></And></Where></Query></View>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below CAML Query:

```
<Where>
    <And>
        <Eq>
            <FieldRef Name="Department_x003a_ID" LookupId="True" />
            <Value Type="Integer">" + deptID + "</Value>
        </Eq>
        <Eq>
            <FieldRef Name="ID" />
            <Value Type="Integer">" + itemID + "</Value>
        </Eq>
    </And>
</Where>
```